# Child component not rendering with React Router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am trying my hands on React Nested routing & this is my how my app looks like

Posts.js (Parent (plural) Component) which is rendering fine.

```
import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";


import Post from "./Post";
import { Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";


const Posts = ({ match }) => {
 return (
    <div>
        <h2>Topics</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <Link to={`${match.url}/rendering`}>Rendering with React</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
                <Link to={`${match.url}/components`}>Components</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
                <Link to={`${match.url}/props-v-state`}>Props v. State</Link>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div>

            <Route path={`${match.path}/:topicId`} component={Post} />
            <Route
                exact
                path={match.path}
                render={() => <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>}
            />
        </div>

    </div>
)}

export default Posts;
```

Post Component (Child (Singular) Component)

```
import React from "react";

const Post = ({ match }) => (
 <div>
    <h1>Child component</h1>
    <h3>{match.params.topicId}</h3>
 </div>
 );
export default Post;
```

Not sure what config is lacking here, the parent component is rendering fine on the route while the child component content is not rendering

No error in console.

---

Parent Routing Configuration

```
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route,NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./container/home/Home";
import About from "./container/about/About";
import Posts from "./container/post/posts";
import PageNotFound from "./container/Error/404";

const routes = () => (
 <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home}></Route>
    <Route path="/about" component={About}></Route>
    <Route exact path="/post" component={Posts}></Route>
    <Route component={PageNotFound}> </Route>*/}
  </Switch>

  )


 export default routes;
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Layout from "./hoc/layout/layout";



class App extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
    <Layout></Layout>
 );
}}

export default App;
```

Comment: Does it not render at all or only on clicking of link

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri, Nether direct navigation nor click hyper link rendering content

Comment: How is the Posts component rendered. Also whats the url/pathname that you are trying to visit

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri, post component is rendered at /post & child component url /post/linkText

Comment: Ok, one last question, can you show the Route that renders the Posts component

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri adding to the post.Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the mistake in your code is pretty trivial. In the parent Route, i.e the Route that is rendering `Posts` component, you have an `exact` keyword and hence `Routes` like `/posts/:postId` won't match this exact Route with path `/post` and hence the inner Routes or nested Child Routes won't work

You need to change your Routes config like

```
const routes = () => (
     <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home}></Route>
        <Route path="/about" component={About}></Route>
        <Route path="/post" component={Posts}></Route>
        <Route component={PageNotFound}> </Route>*/}
      </Switch>
  )

  export default routes;
```

Comment: Really!! I just checked. Found you're right.. Thanks

Comment: @Kgn-web Glad to have helped :-)

Comment: Will mark your ans as accepted as soon as it allows. Thanks again & Please upvote the post if you think its worth